# React Native Navigation : Navigate to another Stack Navigation (Nested)

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, typescript-typings, react-native-navigation

I'm trying since few hours to navigate from a StackNavigation to another Stack navigation.
I'm using typescript and this is not easy to define right types for all screens.

I made the exemple below of my error.
In this case, when my application start, the first screen is `ProfilHome`.
In this screen I have two button :

- One to go to another screen of my current stackNavigation `ProfilInfo`
- Another to go to another Stacknavigation `MarketStack` and the screen `MarketInfo`

When i click on the first button, there is no problem. but when I click on the second button I got the error :

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"MarketInfo"} was not handled by any navigator.
Do you have a screen named 'MarketInfo'?
```

Error code :

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native'
import { ReactElement } from 'react'
import {createStackNavigator, StackNavigationProp, StackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/stack'
import {useNavigation} from "@react-navigation/native";

//**********************//
// Profile component
//**********************//
type ProfileNavigationStack = {
    ProfilHome: undefined,
    ProfilInfo: undefined,
}
type ProfileHomeNavProps = StackScreenProps<ProfileNavigationStack, 'ProfilHome'>

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator<ProfileNavigationStack>()
const ProfileComponent = () => {
    return (
        <ProfileStack.Navigator>
            <ProfileStack.Screen
                options={{ headerTitle: 'ProfilHome' }}
                name="ProfilHome"
                component={ProfileHome}
            />
            <ProfileStack.Screen
                options={{ headerTitle: 'ProfilInfo' }}
                name="ProfilInfo"
                component={ProfileInfo}
            />
        </ProfileStack.Navigator>
    )
}

const ProfileHome = ({ navigation }: ProfileHomeNavProps) => {
    const navToMarket = useNavigation<MarketHomeNavProps>()

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>ProfileHome</Text>
            <Button title={'goToInfo'} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ProfilInfo')}/>
            <Button title={'goToMarket'} onPress={() => navToMarket.navigate('MarketInfo')}/>
        </View>
    )
}
const ProfileInfo = () => (<View><Text>ProfileInfo</Text></View>)

//**********************//
// Market component
//**********************//
type MarketNavigationStack = {
    MarketHome: undefined,
    MarketInfo: undefined,
}
type MarketHomeNavProps = StackNavigationProp<MarketNavigationStack, 'MarketHome'>

const MarketStack = createStackNavigator<MarketNavigationStack>()
const MarketComponent = () => {
    return (
        <MarketStack.Navigator>
            <MarketStack.Screen
                options={{ headerTitle: 'ProfilHome' }}
                name="MarketHome"
                component={MarketHome}
            />
            <MarketStack.Screen
                options={{ headerTitle: 'MarketInfo' }}
                name="MarketInfo"
                component={MarketInfo}
            />
        </MarketStack.Navigator>
    )
}

const MarketHome = () => (<View><Text>MarketHome</Text></View>)
const MarketInfo = () => (<View><Text>MarketHome</Text></View>)


//**********************//
// Main component
//**********************//
type HomeNavigationStack = {
    Profile: undefined,
    Market: undefined,
}
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator<HomeNavigationStack>()

export default function StartApp(): ReactElement {
    return (
        <HomeStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerShown: false,
            }}
        >
            <HomeStack.Screen
                name="Profile"
                component={ProfileComponent}
            />
            <HomeStack.Screen
                name="Market"
                component={MarketComponent}
            />
        </HomeStack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

I think the solution is [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#nesting-navigators) but I don't understand how it's really works.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, if your component is passed to a stack or any other navigator container that can directly pass navigation prop, you don't really need to use `useNavigation` hook like here, it's useful if you can't access the `navigation` prop directly, [useNavigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/).

```
const ProfileHome = ({ navigation }: ProfileHomeNavProps) => {
    const navToMarket = useNavigation<MarketHomeNavProps>()/// <-- that isn't needed, you can directly use navigation prop

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>ProfileHome</Text>
            <Button title={'goToInfo'} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ProfilInfo')}/>
            <Button title={'goToMarket'} onPress={() => navToMarket.navigate('MarketInfo')}/> ///<-- so instead of using navToMarket you can just use navigation as you have used it in navigating to 'ProfilInfo'
        </View>
    )
}
```

And then, to navigate to a screen in a nested in another stack, you can pass a stack name and object with `screen` prop that will be your screen name in that stack. 
Since your 'nested' stack name is "Market" in your root(`HomeStack`) component, and in your "Market" stack, the required screen name is "MarketInfo", you should use navigation function like this:

```
navigation.navigate('Market', { screen: 'MarketInfo' })
```

You can read more about nested navigators/navigating to a nested screen in [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator).

Comment: When using your nested solution, it's works yes, but I got a typescript error :

`Argument of type '["Market", { screen: string; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type '["ProfilHome" | "ProfilInfo"] | ["ProfilHome" | "ProfilInfo", undefined]'`

Comment: you need to add MarketInfo route to your ```ProfileNavigationStack```, you need to define all routes that can be navigated from the stack, in the corresponding type declaration, you can put ```Market: { screen: string }``` in that type and the error should be gone.